# XPath: Select specific item from property string

Tags: python, xpath

Trying to drill down to a specific Xpath of a url in a longer string. I've gotten down to each of the listed blocks, but can't seem to get any further than the long string of properties.

example code:

```
<div class="abc class">
    <a class="123" title="abc" keys="xyz" href="url string">
```

Right now I have...

```
.//*[@id='content']/div/div[1]/a
```

That only retrieves the whole string of data, from class through href.  What would I need to just retrieve the "url string" from that part? Would this need to be accomplished with a subsequent 'for' argument in the python input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure XPath solution would involve just adding the `@href` to the expression:

```
.//*[@id='content']/div/div[1]/a/@href
```

In Python, assuming you are using `lxml.html`, you can get the attribute using the `.attrib`:

```
for link in root.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/div/div[1]/a"):
    print(link.attrib['href'])
```

Comment: Dang it all, I was so close... Thank you! @alecxe

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid this array

if your class name is unique you can do it like:-

```
//*[@id='content']/div/div[@class='abc class']/a[@keys='xyz']/@href
```

Hope it will help you :)